# When i click a list item i want to store it name in an edittext

Tags: android, jquery, list, listview

I am creating an eWallet application like many existing ones. I have lots of classes that do different stuff but i need some advice in a group of them. I have created a listview witch fetches the categories i have created and saved in a phpMyAdmin database. I am displaying this data on a list view successfully. This list view just shows the list of the categories to the user and if he clicks a list item a new activity appers which llows him to edit or delete the list item.
Now i used the same code (i lterally used the same code!) to create a **second** listview inside a dialog box. Imagine that this listview appears inside the dialog box when i click an edit text which has an on click listener. I successfully display the data in this second list view as well. Now on this dialog box when i click a list item/category (lets say Sports category) i want the name of the edit text to change to the category i chose. But i am confused because i use the same code and methods that open the edit and delete activity on my **first** list view. I hope i did not confuse you too much.

Here is the code that downloads the data in my list views.

```
import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.content.Context;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.Toast;
import java.io.BufferedInputStream;
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.net.HttpURLConnection;
import java.net.MalformedURLException;
import java.net.URL;

public class ExDownloaderActivity extends AsyncTask<Void, Integer, String>
{
Context context;
String address;
ListView expenseListView;

ProgressDialog progressDialog;

public ExDownloaderActivity(Context context, String address, ListView exCategoryListView)
{
    this.context = context;
    this.address = address;
    this.expenseListView = exCategoryListView;
}

//B4 JOB STARTS
@Override
protected void onPreExecute()
{
    super.onPreExecute();

    progressDialog = new ProgressDialog(context);
    progressDialog.setTitle("Fetch Data");
    progressDialog.setMessage("Fetching Data...Please wait");
    progressDialog.show();
}

@Override
protected String doInBackground(Void... params)
{
    String data = downloadData();
    return data;
}

@Override
protected void onProgressUpdate(Integer... values)
{
    super.onProgressUpdate(values);
}

@Override
protected void onPostExecute(String string)
{
    super.onPostExecute(string);

    progressDialog.dismiss();

    if(string != null)
    {
        ExParserActivity parser = new ExParserActivity(context, string, expenseListView);
        parser.execute();
    }

    else
    {
        Toast.makeText(context, "Unable to download data",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
}

private String downloadData()
{
    //connect and get a stream of data
    InputStream inputStream = null;
    //to store each line
    String line = null;

    try
    {
        URL url = new URL(address);
        HttpURLConnection httpURLConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
        inputStream = new BufferedInputStream(httpURLConnection.getInputStream());

        BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inputStream));

        StringBuffer stringBuffer = new StringBuffer();

        if(bufferedReader!= null)
        {
            while ((line = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null)
            {
                stringBuffer.append(line + "\n");
            }
        }

        else
        {
            return null;
        }

        return stringBuffer.toString();
    }

    catch (MalformedURLException e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    catch (IOException e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    finally
    {
        if(inputStream != null)
        {
            try
            {
                inputStream.close();
            }

            catch (IOException e)
            {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }

    return null;
}
}
```

**Second Class**

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.support.design.widget.Snackbar;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.Toast;
import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class ExParserActivity extends AsyncTask<Void, Integer, Integer>
{
Context context;
ListView exListView;
String data;

ArrayList<String> exCategories = new ArrayList<>();
ProgressDialog progressDialog;

public ExParserActivity(Context context, String data, ListView lv)
{
    this.context = context;
    this.data = data;
    this.exListView = lv;
}

//B4 JOB STARTS
@Override
protected void onPreExecute()
{
    super.onPreExecute();

    progressDialog = new ProgressDialog(context);
    progressDialog.setTitle("Parser");
    progressDialog.setMessage("Parsing...Please wait");
    progressDialog.show();
}

//Heavy job
@Override
protected Integer doInBackground(Void... params)
{
    return this.parse();
}

@Override
protected void onProgressUpdate(Integer... values)
{
    super.onProgressUpdate(values);
}

@Override
protected void onPostExecute(Integer integer)
{
    super.onPostExecute(integer);

    progressDialog.dismiss();

    if(integer == 1)
    {
        //ADAPTER
        ArrayAdapter<String> arrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(context, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, exCategories);

        //ADAPT TO LIST VIEW
        exListView.setAdapter(arrayAdapter);

        //ON CLICK LISTENER
        exListView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener()
        {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id)
            {
                context.startActivity(new Intent(context, UpdateDeleteExCategories.class));
                //Snackbar.make(view, exCategories.get(position), Snackbar.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });
    }

    else
    {
        Toast.makeText(context, "Unable to Parse", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
}

//PARSE RECEIVED DATA
private int parse()
{
    try
    {
        //ADD THAT DATA TO JSON ARRAY FIRST
        JSONArray jsonArray = new JSONArray(data);

        //CREATE JO OBJECT TO HOLD A SINGLE ITEM
        JSONObject jsonObject = null;

        exCategories.clear();

        //LOOP THROUGH THE ARRAY
        for(int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++)
        {
            jsonObject = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);

            //RETRIEVE NAME
            String exCatName = jsonObject.getString("exCatName");

            //ADD IT TO ARRAY LIST
            exCategories.add(exCatName);
        }

        //IF ITS SUCCESSFUL RETURN 1
        return 1;
    }

    catch (JSONException e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    //IF IT IS NOT SUCCESSFUL RETURN 0
    return 0;
}
}
```

**Third Class**

```
import android.app.DatePickerDialog;
import android.app.Dialog;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.DatePicker;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.TextView;

import java.util.Calendar;

public class AddExpenseActivity extends SwipeFunctionActivity
{
private ImageView backImageView;
private TextView setDateTextView;
private EditText categoryEditText, amountEditText;
int year, month, day;
static final int DIALOG_ID = 0; //Initialise the variable to 0.

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_add_expense);

    final Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
    year = calendar.get(Calendar.YEAR);
    month = calendar.get(Calendar.MONTH);
    day = calendar.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);

    setDateTextView = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.setDateTextView);
    backImageView = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.backImageView);
    categoryEditText = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.categoryEditText);
    amountEditText = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.amountEditText);

        setDateTextView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
        {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v)
        {
            showDialog(DIALOG_ID);
        }
    });

    categoryEditText.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
    {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v)
        {
            pickCategoryMethod();
        }
    });

    backImageView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
    {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v)
        {
            backMethod();
        }
    });
   }

@Override
protected Dialog onCreateDialog(int id)
{
    if (id == DIALOG_ID)
    {
        return new DatePickerDialog(this, dpickerListener, year, month, day);
    }
    return null;
}

private DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener dpickerListener = new DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener()
{
    @Override
    public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int year, int monthOfYear, int dayOfMonth)
    {
        AddExpenseActivity.this.year = year;
        month = monthOfYear + 1;
        day = dayOfMonth;

        showDate(AddExpenseActivity.this.year, month, day);
        //Toast.makeText(AddExpenseActivity.this, "Selected date: " + dayOfMonth + " / " + (monthOfYear+1) + " / " + year, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
};

private void showDate(int year, int month, int day)
{
    setDateTextView.setText(new StringBuilder().append(day).append("/")
            .append(month).append("/").append(year));
}

public void pickCategoryMethod()
{
    String url = "http://192.168.0.3/myapp/fexcateg.php";
    //

    final Dialog dialog = new Dialog(AddExpenseActivity.this);
    dialog.setContentView(R.layout.activity_pick_category);
    dialog.setTitle("         Pick your Category");

    final ListView pickCategoryListView = (ListView)dialog.findViewById(R.id.pickCategoryListView);
    final ExDownloaderActivity downloader = new ExDownloaderActivity(this, url, pickCategoryListView);

    //Execute download
    downloader.execute();

    //pickCategoryListView = (ListView)dialog.findViewById(R.id.pickCategoryListView);

    //This makes the dialog visible.
    dialog.show();
}

public void backMethod()
{
    //startActivity(new Intent(getApplicationContext(), BalanceActivity.class));
    finish();
}

@Override
public void onSwipeLeft()
{
    super.onSwipeLeft();
    startActivity(new Intent(getApplicationContext(), AddIncomeActivity.class));
    finish();
}

@Override
public void onSwipeRight()
{
    super.onSwipeRight();
    startActivity(new Intent(getApplicationContext(), AddSavingActivity.class));
    finish();
}
}
```

So for my problem now. I want when i click a category inside the dialog box, the categoryEditText variable i have in the trird class to change in the name of the item i clicked in the listview. First of all where do i have to write this code and secondly how to do it. I am kind of lost becasue is really a big app:/ 
Many thanks !!!

Comment: No one can help me? :(

Comment: Hello everyone, i still need help with this. Please can someone at least have a look?